# XML Namespace url generating X001 instead of 2001

Tags: xml, xml-namespaces, application-xml

Anyone knows why XML name space is populating as `http://www.w3.org/X001/XMLSchema-instance` in mapped request instead of `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance`

The mapped request has XML defined objects and all have schema namespace `http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema`.

Comment: Generating/populating from what?  Your question cannot be answered at the XML level alone.

Comment: @kjhughes thanks for your input. It's a spring boot application that accepts application/json, uses the json field values to map to application/xml object to make a downstream call using RestTemplate

Comment: Post a [mcve] and update tagging to reflect libraries/tools in play.

Comment: Without knowing exactly what you're doing we have no way of knowing why the output of whatever you're doing is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Cause: the X in X001 was caused by custom masking. After turning off masking flag, I was able to see correct logging of namespace a http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema